# ffmpeg always asks if I want to replace the input file

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge a video source and an  audio file together to end on the shortest flag with the latest ffmpeg build from zeranoe but all it does is ask if I want to replace the audio or video file (with a corrupted empty file to add).  The output ends up being corrupt or missing one of the files too.

```
 C:\Users\Apps\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -i audio.ogg video.webm -c copy -shortest new.web
m
ffmpeg version N-69835-g03adafb Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3
 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --ena
ble-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --e
nable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-lib
gsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencor
e-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enabl
e-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-l
ibtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-
libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-l
ibwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --ena
ble-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 18.100 / 54. 18.100
  libavcodec     56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavformat    56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.100 /  5. 11.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, ogg, from 'audio.ogg':
  Duration: 00:00:26.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 84 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 112 kb/s
    Metadata:
      TITLE           : SpikexTwilight.wmv
      ENCODER         : Lavf56.22.100
File 'video.webm' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot an `-i`:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.ogg -i video.webm …
                     ^
                     |
                     |
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you, I've been trying to figure this out for months thanks ^-^